# SSDT tabular model data loading / ID error

Tags: sql, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I am new to Visual studio, and I am in the process of building my first tabular model in Visual studio, have been using powerBI for a year or so.

I have an Azure SQL database setup, with data tables. I can access the database fine through SSMS, Power BI etc fine. I can also access the data fine when using the data model on the workspace server rather than an integrated workspace with VS.

When using the model in integrated workspace mode, when I use "Getting data" through power query in my tabular project in visual studio, I can login into the database fine, I can preview the various data tables and open them in power query / transform etc. However, when I try to import the data - it can get past stage one of the processing - and I get the following error

> “Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLE DB
>   or ODBC error: We're sorry, an error occurred during evaluation..”

Which leaves me with a table with headers for the columns - but no actual rows of data.

When I revert the data model back to workspace server (i.e. integrated workspace set to false) - I can upload / refresh the data.

So I was happily building my model on the workspace server - HOWEVER - when I came to adding roles and user to those roles - I cannot use the workspace server - or I get an ID error - as I am using an Azure AD. - see below

An error occurred while opening the model on the workspace database.

> Reason: Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned:
>   'ID cannot be specified for Azure Analysis Services role member:
>   'member@domain'.

This ID error is fixed when I use an integrated workspace - as recommended - but then I can't load the data in.

So I am stuck between:

- integrated workspace with no data
- workspace server  - without the ability to add AzureAD IDs

Any help with either of the issues would be much appreciated

Thanks,
Laurence

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you found the solution ? Thank you for your help

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you found the solution ? Thank you for your help

Comment: The issue of not being able to process data when using the integrated workspace still exists. When switching to a local AS instance as the workspace server processing works fine, so it's not the model or the database driver. I suspect there's something wrong or missing with the implementation of Azure authentication (or oAuth in general) on the integrated workspace server.

Answer (score 0):

I work with VS 2017 and experience exactly the same issue. I use SSDT compability level 1400.

I appears that simply run Visual Studio as administrator solves the issue with Integrated server.

Accidentally found this solution, I saw earlier some people had solved inability to connect to workspace server without admin rights.

Comment: @Lidou123 check if it's still relevant for you